# Can´t see Owner Account in Restricted Profile

Tags: android, security, accountmanager, restricted-profiles

I have a huge problem, in the Android Documentation says that if I add

```
android:restrictedAccountType="com.example.account.type"
```

to the Application Manifest I was going to be able to find the owner account with the specified AccountType.

In my code and also the SyncAdapter code from the google samples, this rule doesn't work, but if I use the AccountType "com.google" I can find the owners Google Accounts from the Restricted profile... Clearly something is missing in this Documentation, but I can´t seem to find any actual working example of this problem.